# Python, given a word, generate a list with one letter changing for each letter in alphabet

Tags: python

Here is my problem:

> Return the number of times that the string `code` appears anywhere in the given string, except we'll accept any letter for the `d`, so `cope` and `cooe` count.

I solved it by creating a list with all 26 possible `co_e` combinations and then used two for loops to iterate through the list and search for matches in the given string.

Is there another way I could have created that list? or is there a way to ignore the third character in word and only search for matching characters 1, 2 and 4?

Here is my solution:

```
if len(inputstring)<4:
    return 0
wordlist=['coae','cobe','coce','code'...etc]
count=0

for i in wordlist:
    for j in range(len(inputstring)):
        if inputstring[j:j+4] == i:
            count+=1
return count
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I realize you did this on the SO question, but just so no one gets the wrong idea on this site: **Do not** edit a questioner's code with improvements. If you have improvements to suggest, **post an answer**.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes yup, it’s relatively common to do so on SO, and I did do before deciding on migration. I’m aware you shouldn’t do so here, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't see any harm in leaving it; I just don't want people seeing the comment from another site and assuming it's okay here, too.

Comment: Right, comment nuked.

Answer (score 6):

Just use regular expressions!

```
import re
# creating regular expression with "any" letter at 3 position
r = re.compile("co[a-z]e")
# and taking all the matches:
matches = r.findall("some of my code, nope to come, cofe and cole, or cope and dome, rope and hope!")
count = len(matches)
print(count)
```

Comment: `print(len(matches or []))`.

Comment: You right! the count was needed!

Comment: `findall()` always returns a list, there is no need to use `or` here. `len(matches)` will always work.

Comment: It's true, my bad :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in` to test if a substring appears:

```
>>> 'code' in 'recoded'
True
```

This removes the  need to loop over the string.

You can generate your test strings by looping over all letters in the alphabet; Python already has the latter available for you at [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import string

possibilities = ['co{l}e'.format(l) for l in string.ascii_lowercase]

count = 0
for possibility in possibilities:
    if possibility in inputstring:
        count += 1
```

You could also just test for `co` appearing, and see if there is a letter `e` further along. You can use the [`str.find()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to find the position of an occurrence and search from there; `str.find()` takes a starting position to search for the next match:

```
count = 0
start = 0
while True:
    position = inputstring.find('co')
    if position == -1:
        # not found, end the search
        break
    if len(inputstring) > position + 2 and inputstring[position + 2] == 'e':
        count += 1
    start = position + 1
```

However, most experienced programmers will use [*regular expressions*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to find such matches:

```
import re

count = len(re.findall(r'co[a-z]e', inputstring))
```

Here the expression uses `[a-z]` to match a single character as a *class*, anything in that series (so letters from `a` to `z`) would match. The [`re.findall()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of all matches found in the input string, so all you have to do then is take the `len()` length of that list to get a count.

Comment: ['co{l}e'.format(l) for l in string.ascii_lowercase] - possible, regular expression engine make something like this under the hood when you use "co[a-z]e" pattern :)

Comment: @MihanEntalpo: a little patience please, I'll get there too! Take into account this user is probably still in the early stages of learning to program, and regular expressions can be quite challenging.

Comment: "*This removes the need to loop over the string.*" Strictly speaking, it doesn't remove the loop; you just don't need to do it manually, and there might be some cool optimizations done (for example, if it matches the first three letters of `code`, then you can skip over those three, since `o` won't match `c`)

Comment: Also, would it be (marginally) more efficient to use a generator instead of a list comprehension? i.e. with `()` around it instead of `[]`.

Comment: Right, it removes the need to manually loop *in Python*.  The C implementation of the containment search is [based on Boyer-Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220418/runtime-of-pythons-if-substring-in-string/35220792#35220792); the algorithm does skip in larger steps where possible.

Comment: And yes, a generator expression would be slightly more efficient (certainly in terms of memory, less so in terms of speed). I answered with a focus on teaching a beginner however, not with a focus on code review, so I ignored that option for simplicity’s sake.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and beautiful. I hope it is what you want

```
import re

list=['coae','cobe','coce','code','coco']
count=0

for i in list:
  if re.match(r'co[a-z]e', i):
    count+=1

print(count)
```